# What is an efficient way to sort times in the format min:sec, without importing any modules?

Tags: python, list, sorting, timedelta

I have a table of strings where the final column is the 'time' is written as below:

```
['7:15','6:27','5:24','2:50','4:39','5:11','2:56','4:29','3:17','3:04']
```

I would like to present the largest and smallest from this list, with the **restriction** being I **cannot import any modules** (it's not my choice to).

While I thought of comparing the first character of each element as an int, then if there is a tie, looking at the 2nd number to compare, it seems like there could be a better way?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`list.sort`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) method with your own key function:

```
l = ['7:15','6:27','5:24','2:50','4:39','5:11','2:56','4:29','3:17','3:04']
l.sort(lambda s: [int(i) for i in s.split(':')])
```

which modifies `l` to:

```
['2:50', '2:56', '3:04', '3:17', '4:29', '4:39', '5:11', '5:24', '6:27', '7:15']
```

Answer (score 1):

The traditional method *is* to use an imported module, e.g. [`datetime.timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) from `stlib`. However, given your restriction you can calculate minutes in each "time delta" string and then sort:

```
def sorter(x):
    hrs, mins = map(int, x.split(':'))
    return 60*hrs + mins

res = sorted(L, key=sorter)

print(res)

['2:50', '2:56', '3:04', '3:17', '4:29', '4:39', '5:11', '5:24', '6:27', '7:15']
```